# Matplotlib colorbar: how to manually set the intervals?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I am using the following snippet to create a custom colorbar:

```
import pylab as pl
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[0,10000,100000,400000,500000]])
pl.figure(figsize=(9, 1.5))
mycmap = colors.ListedColormap(['yellow','orange','red','darkred'])
img = pl.imshow(a, cmap=mycmap)
pl.gca().set_visible(False)
cax = pl.axes([0.1, 0.2, 0.8, 0.6])
cbar=pl.colorbar(orientation='horizontal', cax=cax,spacing='proportional');
cbar.set_ticks([0,10000,100000,400000,500000])
cbar.set_ticklabels(['0','10000','100000','400000','500000'])
```

This is giving me a colorbar with regular intervals, although I have specified `spacing='proportional'`:
[image]

The intended result is, instead:

```
0-10000: yellow
10001-100000: orange
100001-400000: red
400001-500000: dark red
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you want to set the ticklabels at the coloredges or do you want to have the colors represent the given values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As can be seen when not turning the axes invisible, the colorbar is correctly representing the color of the data in the image.

[image]

If this is not what you want you should start by establishing how the data is represented in the image. Introducing a Normalization for the data to the colormap range is usually the way this is accomplished. Here a `BoundaryNorm` makes sense.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[0,10000,100000,400000,500000]])
plt.figure(figsize=(4, 2.5))

mycmap = matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(['yellow','orange','red','darkred'])
norm = matplotlib.colors.BoundaryNorm(a[0], len(a[0])-1)
img = plt.imshow(a, cmap=mycmap, norm=norm)
cax = plt.axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.1])
cbar=plt.colorbar(orientation='horizontal', cax=cax,spacing='proportional');

plt.show()
```

This now gives a meaningful representation with ticks at the edges of the colorranges.

[image]