# Assign Color to Specific Value in matplotlib through Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've got a chart produced in matplotlib that's basically a checkered grid. I've got four values and I want to assign each specific value a color on the grid. I do not want to use a colormap because that shows a gradient of values and that's not what I want. I have the values -1, 0, 1, 10. Is there a way to do this?

I don't think I can include the code without including the entirety of it because it's just a couple lines that relate to the grid but there's a lot of stuff that intermingles. Let's just say I have something that looks like

|1|-1|0|0|-1|1|

|0|1|1|-1|0|1|

|-10|1|1|0|1|1|

and because the way color maps work, the -10 is skewing the outcome because 1,0,-1 are all much closer to each other than -10. Instead I would like each number to just be assigned one color.

Comment: Can you show the expected output?

Comment: Yes there is a way to do this, probably even several. If the question is *how* to do this, please give us something to work with. That would mostly be the [mcve] of the code that does not work for you when you try it.

Comment: I think you misunderstand [mcve]. You need to create such example, such that it reproduces the problem and allows people to understand it and eventually modify it with the solution.

Comment: In any case, something similar has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47776318/plotting-a-2d-numpy-array-with-custom-colors) already. You may want to state in how far this does not help.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47774935/matplotlib-colorbar-how-to-manually-set-the-intervals) may equally show you a possible solution. Again make sure to state in how far existing answer are not helping.

Answer (score 1):

You could look into using a qualitative colormap from https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html instead of one based on a gradient. They might fit your type of data more effectively.

Looking something like

[image]