# Matplotlib: ListedColormap not mapping colors

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am having trouble understanding why a custom `cmap` is not being properly mapped to an image using `plt.imshow`.

When I plot the 2-D array `resr` without specifying a cmap, I see:

```
resr = np.array([[0,2],[3,4]],dtype=int)
plt.imshow(resr)
```

[image]

This looks right. When I try and pass a cmap of my specified colors using:

```
cmap1 = ['#7fc97f', '#ffff99', '#386cb0', '#f0027f']
cmap = colors.ListedColormap(cmap1) 
plt.imshow(resr, cmap=cmap)
```

I see:

[image]

For some reason,  the color `cmap1[3]` is being mapped to the `resr` values `3` and `4`. Why is this happening?

Comment: I think the reason becomes clear if you add a colorbar (via `plt.colorbar()`).

Comment: I see.  Is there a way to make the colors be mapped categorically? (i.e. `cmap1[0]` to `0`, `cmap1[1]` to `2`, `cmap1[2]` to `3`, and `cmap1[3]` to `4`)?

Comment: I think that any value greater than 3 will be mapped with cmap1[3] (cmap1[4] is out of index).  You can get the expected output with `resr = np.array([[0,1],[2,3]],dtype=int)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47776318/plotting-a-2d-numpy-array-with-custom-colors

Comment: or maybe this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47774935/matplotlib-colorbar-how-to-manually-set-the-intervals

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thank you!  You came to the rescue again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two options here:

#### A. Map data to categories

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.colors as colors
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

resr = np.array([[0,2],[3,4]],dtype=int)
u, ind = np.unique(resr, return_inverse=True)
norm = colors.BoundaryNorm(np.arange(len(u)+1)-.5, len(u))
cmap1 = ['#7fc97f', '#ffff99', '#386cb0', '#f0027f']
cmap = colors.ListedColormap(cmap1) 

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(ind.reshape(resr.shape), cmap=cmap,norm=norm)
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%")

cb = plt.colorbar(im, cmap=cmap,norm=norm,cax=cax)

cb.set_ticks(np.arange(len(u)))
cb.ax.set_yticklabels(cmap1)
cb.ax.tick_params(labelsize=10)

plt.show()
```

#### B. Map categories to data

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.colors as colors
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

resr = np.array([[0,2],[3,4]],dtype=int)

u = np.unique(resr)
bounds = np.concatenate(([resr.min()-1], u[:-1]+np.diff(u)/2. ,[resr.max()+1]))
print(bounds)
norm = colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, len(bounds)-1)
cmap1 = ['#7fc97f', '#ffff99', '#386cb0', '#f0027f']
cmap = colors.ListedColormap(cmap1) 

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(resr, cmap=cmap,norm=norm)
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%")

cb = plt.colorbar(im, cmap=cmap,norm=norm,cax=cax)

cb.set_ticks(bounds[:-1]+np.diff(bounds)/2.)
cb.ax.set_yticklabels(cmap1)
cb.ax.tick_params(labelsize=10)

plt.show()
```

The result is the same for both cases.

[image]

Comment: This is still helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Following @ImportanceOfBeingErnest's comment providing a link to their [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47774935/matplotlib-colorbar-how-to-manually-set-the-intervals), I was able to find a solution.

The trick was to use pass `np.unique(resr)` to [BoundaryNorm](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.BoundaryNorm.html). Something like:

```
resr = np.array([[0,2],[3,4]],dtype=int)

norm = colors.BoundaryNorm(np.unique(resr), len(np.unique(resr))-1)
cmap1 = ['#7fc97f', '#ffff99', '#386cb0', '#f0027f']
cmap = colors.ListedColormap(cmap1) 
plt.imshow(resr, cmap=cmap,norm=norm);plt.colorbar()
```

Which returns the expected result:

[image]

Comment: The problem with this is that the boundaries should be the *edges* of the data bins. Hence the length of the boundary list need to be one more than the number of unique elements in the data.