# matplotlib: Colorbar Mapping for discontinuous integers

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, colorbar

I have a project where I am trying to plot 2D arrays that are integer types. The values can vary from 0 to 4 and may not all be present.

I started developing my plotting routine with an integer array `resr`, a listed colormap `cmap`, and a [colormap index based on discrete intervals](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.BoundaryNorm.html)  `norm`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.colors as colors
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

resr = np.array([[0,2],[3,4]],dtype=int)

norm = colors.BoundaryNorm(np.unique(resr), len(np.unique(resr))-1)
cmap1 = ['#7fc97f', '#ffff99', '#386cb0', '#f0027f']
cmap = colors.ListedColormap(cmap1) 

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(resr, cmap=cmap,norm=norm)
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%")
bounds = 0.5+np.arange(norm.N+1)
cb = plt.colorbar(im, cmap=cmap,norm=norm,boundaries=bounds,cax=cax)
tic_locs =1+np.arange(norm.N+1)
cb.set_ticks(tic_locs)
cb.ax.set_yticklabels(cmap1)
cb.ax.tick_params(labelsize=10)
```

Which returns the expected result:

[image]

When I change `resr` to test to make sure the plotting routine will work in other situations:

```
resr = np.array([[0,1],[3,4]],dtype=int)
```

The image plots correctly, but the colorbar is not being formatted correctly:

[image]

Why is this happening?

Comment: If you define `bounds` independent on the data, and hence the norm that is used, the result will most likely be wrong.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest could you elaborate more?  `bounds` is defined using `norm.N`, which is defined using the data.  I am consused.

Comment: Apparently the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52842553/matplotlib-listedcolormap-not-mapping-colors/52932972#52932972) was still not answered correctly. So I provided a solution over there.