# pyplot: define customised colormap for image plot which assigns a color to a certain value

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors

What is the easiest way to display an array with only very few different values as an image plot, e.g. with `imshow` from `matplotlib.pyplot`, assigning fixed colors to each of the values that show up in the array? For instance, if the array contained only the binary values 0 and 1, I would like to be able to draw all value-0-pixels in yellow and all value-1-pixels in green, say. Can this be achieved using a customised colormap or is it necessary to write a new array containing the appropriate rgb tuple for each original value?

Comment: `ListedColormap` would be the way to go.

Comment: @JohanC Thanks for your hint, I thought so too, but wouldn't one have to specify boundaries or something like that then? Or is there a way to indicate a value->color mapping in the ```ListedColormap```?

Comment: If your values are equally-spaced numbers, the correspondence would automatically assign the first color to the smallest value, etc.. See [ListedColormap not mapping colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52842553/matplotlib-listedcolormap-not-mapping-colors) about an approach when the values aren't equally-spaced.

Comment: Great, now I see how it works, thanks. If you care, post your hints as an answer and I will accept it.